# How can I retrieve a RingCentral call recording from a monitored incoming call?

Tags: voice, telephony, voice-recording, ringcentral, call-recording

I'm monitoring incoming calls on RingCentral by listening for the Call Session Notifications (CSN) `telephony/sessions` event filter:

```
/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/telephony/sessions
```

From this, I will receive events like the following. The `recordings` property will appear to indicate a recording is available. How can I retrieve this recording?

```
{
  "uuid":"12345678901234567890",
  "event":"/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/extension/22222222/telephony/sessions",
  "timestamp":"2019-03-08T22:30:40.059Z",
  "subscriptionId":"11112222-3333-4444-5555-666677778888",
  "ownerId":"33333333",
  "body":{
    "sequence":7,
    "sessionId":"1234567890",
    "telephonySessionId":"1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
    "serverId":"10.11.12.13.TAM",
    "eventTime":"2019-03-08T22:30:39.938Z",
    "parties":[
      {
        "accountId":"11111111",
        "extensionId":"22222222",
        "id":"cs12345678901234567890-2",
        "direction":"Inbound",
        "to":{
          "phoneNumber":"+16505550100",
          "name":"Jane Doe",
          "extensionId":"22222222"
        },
        "from":{
          "phoneNumber":"+14155550100",
          "name":"John Smith"
        },
        "recordings":[
          {
            "id":"44444444",
            "active":false
          }
        ],
        "status":{
          "code":"Answered",
          "rcc":false
        },
        "missedCall":false,
        "standAlone":false,
        "muted":false
      }
    ],
    "origin":{
      "type":"Call"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to retrieve the recording using information in the Call Session Notification (CSN) event, specifically the `recordings[0].id` property and the `sessionID` property.

1. retrieving a full media URL by calling the `call-log` endpoint with the `sessionId` property
2. manually creating recording media URL using the `recordings[0].id` property.

> **Note 1:** While the call is ongoing, the recording will not be available for retrieval, even when the recording id is present in the Call Session Notification event. The recording will be available to be retrieved shortly after the call concludes.
>
> **Note 2:** Call recordings can be in MP3 or WAV format determined by the company. To distinguish check the response `Content-Type` header for the MIME type when retrieving the recording media file.

### 1) Retrieving Full Medial URL via Call Log API

Making an intermediate API call to the `call-log` API has the dual benefits of being the official approach for receiving a media URL an providing more metadata for the call. In this approach, the `recording.id` in the `call-log` record will match the `recordings[0].id` property in the Call Session Notification event.

Both the company account and user extension `call-log` APIs can be called with the `sessionId` parameter from the event as shown:

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/~/call-log?sessionId={sessionId}
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/call-log?sessionId={sessionId}
```

In this example, the `sessionId` is `1234567890` so you would have a Company Call Log API URL as follows

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/~/call-log?sessionId=1234567890
```

The response object will have a `recording` property that provides hypermedia links to get the media file. The file can be WAV or MP3 format which is communicated in the response `Content-Type` header.

```
{
  "uri": "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/extension/22222222/call-log?view=Simple&sessionId=1234567890&page=1&perPage=100",
  "records": [
    {
      "uri": "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/extension/22222222/call-log/1234567890ABCDEFGabcdefgh?view=Simple",
      "id": "1234567890ABCDEFGabcdefgh",
      "sessionId": "1234567890",
      "startTime": "2019-03-08T22:30:29.505Z",
      "duration": 35,
      "type": "Voice",
      "direction": "Inbound",
      "action": "Phone Call",
      "result": "Accepted",
      "to": {
        "phoneNumber": "+16505550100",
        "name": "Jane Doe"
      },
      "from": {
        "phoneNumber": "+14155550100",
        "name": "John Smith",
        "location": "San Francisco, CA"
      },
      "recording": {
        "uri": "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/recording/44444444",
        "id": "44444444",
        "type": "OnDemand",
        "contentUri": "https://media.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/111111111/recording/44444444/content"
      },
      "extension": {
        "uri": "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/111111111/extension/22222222",
        "id": 22222222
      },
      "reason": "Accepted",
      "reasonDescription": "The call connected to and was accepted by this number."
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "page": 1,
    "perPage": 100,
    "pageStart": 0,
    "pageEnd": 0
  },
  "navigation": {
    "firstPage": {
      "uri": "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/extension/22222222/call-log?view=Simple&sessionId=1234567890&page=1&perPage=100"
    },
    "lastPage": {
      "uri": "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/extension/22222222/call-log?view=Simple&sessionId=1234567890&page=1&perPage=100"
    }
  }
}
```

### 2) Manually Creating Media URL

You can call the Recording API endpoint and retrieve the media directly by manually constructing the recording URL as follows:

```
https://media.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/recording/{recordingId}/content
```

In this example, the `accountId` is `11111111` and the `recordingId` is `44444444` for the following:

```
https://media.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/recording/44444444/content
```

The `accountId` in the URL path can be set to the currently authorized user's account using `~`. Alternately, it can be set explicitly by extracting the `accountId` from the `event` property or using the `accountId` property in the relevant `party` object. Using `~` is the recommended way to set `accountId`.

> **Note:** This this approach can be quick, it may be error prone as RingCentral has changed the media hostname once in the past. While there are no anticipated, future changes, calling the `call-log` API and retrieving the full media URL from the response is the safer and recommended approach. See below for this approach. This is only included as some people will try this and potentially run into issues later.

### 3) Hybrid Approach

The first approach of calling the `call-log` end point is the recommended approach, however, it involves an extra API call and most of the time the second approach should work fine.

A hybrid approach is to construct the URL as in approach 2 and then fall back to approach 1 if approach 2 returns a 404 or other error.

Comment: Also while the call is live and active, you would not be able to fetch the recording content from Endpoint. The Content will be available as soon as the Call ends.